# Keycloak : custom ExecuteAction Mail, is it possible to get a user custom attribute?

Tags: html-email, freemarker, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm a trying to send a custom mail to my Keycloak user by overiding the executeAction mail template of keycloak.

I have created :

```
../myProject/email/text/executeAction.ftl
../myProject/email/messages/messages_fr.properties
../myProject/email/html/executeAction.ftl
```

I already got a mail working with this html/executeAction.ftl :

```
${msg("executeActionsBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration),user.getFirstName(),user.getLastName(),user.getUsername(),user.getAttributes())}
```

So I know that my configuration is good.
The problem with the above example is that I show a list of user custom attributes when I only want to get one:

gender=Mr  or gender=Mrs

I tried using the function that I saw there :
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/4.5.0.Final/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/UserModel.java

which give the following :

```
<#assign gender= user.getAttributes(gender)/>

${msg("executeActionsBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration),user.getFirstName(),user.getLastName(),user.getUsername(),gender)}
```

I expected to receive a mail with the user gender inside, but no mail is sent:

I have the following error :

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (default task-1) KC-SERVICES0029: Failed to send email: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
      nested exception is:
        java.io.IOException: Exception writing Multipart
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1308)
        at org.keycloak.email.DefaultEmailSenderProvider.send(DefaultEmailSenderProvider.java:142)
        at org.keycloak.email.freemarker.FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.send(FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java:251)

.......
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Exception writing Multipart
        at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:83)
        at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:897)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1652)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1850)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1259)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Empty multipart: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_165447285.1560929205027"
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:81)
    ... 89 more
```

I don't understand what exactly is going wrong :
Is my ftl bad ? I'm no expert but from what I saw, it should be ok.
It looks like keycloak is trying to send the mail, so why suddenly it fail when I try to use a single attribute instead of the full list ?

An other option might be to use some kind of regexp in the .ftl to extract the gender but I don't know if it's possible ?

Edit : Ok, I found out after many trial and error how to do it :

I guess my lack of knowledge about FTL is the problem. I got it working by doing this :

```
<#assign attributes = user.getAttributes()>
<#assign civilite = attributes.civilite?capitalize>
${msg("executeActionsBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration),user.getFirstName(),user.getLastName(),user.getUsername(),civilite)}
```

I have no idea why I needed to drop the ${} part or why you would get the value in HashMap> by doing attributes.key instead of using a getter but well it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out after many trial and error how to do it :

I guess my lack of knowledge about FTL is the problem. I got it working by doing this :

```
<#assign attributes = user.getAttributes()>
<#assign civilite = attributes.civilite?capitalize>
${msg("executeActionsBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration),user.getFirstName(),user.getLastName(),user.getUsername(),civilite)}
```

I have no idea why I needed to drop the ${} part or why you would get the value in HashMap> by doing attributes.key instead of using a getter but well it works...